# ¿Cómo superponer un video?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Utilizando `HTML5`, `CSS3` y/o `JavaScript`.

¿Cómo sería adecuado para que al reproducir un video se ponga adelante y lo demas quede como sombreado? Les muestro esta imagen, aun no tengo nada de código pero quiero hacer algo similar a lo que les voy a mostrar

[image: Ese sería mi objetivo]

Sí está mal que pregunte sin tener el código todavía o sí está mal preguntar sin que sea un error, les pido perdón y de ser necesario borro la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, ¿quieres que se inserte un video de youtube? ¿quieres que se muestre como dentro de un pop-up? ¿quieres que se muestre al hacer click en un boton? por favor agrega mas información y si es posible el código que has intentado.

Comment: @the-breaker Creo que se entiende que es lo que quiero hacer, mira las imágenes. Están los videos abajo en la imagen del lado izquierdo y al hacer click en alguno de esos videos suceda lo que sucede en la imagen de la derecha. Y aclaré que todavía no tengo un código completo realizado, no es un error o algo similar, es a lo que quiero llegar. Y no tengo ni siquiera una idea como voy hacer eso por eso pregunto si alguien sabe y me puede guiar o dar una mano.

Comment: Para mostrar videos y otro contenidos como en las imágenes puedes usar [Shadowbox JS](https://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html), creo que es lo mas apropiado a tu problema ademas que no es muy complicado de aprender y utilizar.

Comment: @the-breaker Genial! Mañana seguro voy a escribir el código, y voy a usar Shadowbox. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, si tienes algún problema voy a estar cerca para ayudar, que tangas buen finde.

Comment: Yo no utilizaría Shadowbox.js, aunque es bueno con las imágenes, con los videos te pide usar Flash Player, que como bien se sabe desde hace tiempo es obsoleto por sus graves problemas de seguridad, esto ha hecho que navegadores como Chrome, los bloquee de forma predeterminada. En su lugar, con simple jQuery se puede lograr lo que deseas.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Me podrias dejar algun link, video o algo para ver como lo haría con jQuery?

Comment: @AgustinAvila revisa esto: https://codepen.io/smallma009/pen/JKEQEd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el contenedor del video ya esta en la pagina lo sobrepones sobre la imagen con `position absolute` y lo centras, si no esta en la pagina puedes añadirlo con un botón en el `event click` con `createElement`, en cualquiera de los casos al dar clic solo debes cambiar la opacidad del elemento que esta debajo del contenedor tiene el video. Este script es un ejemplo de ello:

```
document.getElementById("contenedorVideo").addEventListener("click", function(){  
 document.getElementById("contenedorDebajoDelVideo").style.opacity="0.7"
});
```